# Timezone change after saving the content

Tags: php, timezone, typo3, typo3-9.x

We need to display a default `starttime` on BE when adding a News (tx_news)

**TCA :**

```
    'starttime' => [
        'exclude' => true,
        'label' => 'LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:starttime_formlabel',
        'config' => [
            'type' => 'input',
            'renderType' => 'inputDateTime',
            'size' => 16,
            'eval' => 'datetime,int',
            'default' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            'behaviour' => [
                'allowLanguageSynchronization' => true,
            ],
        ]
    ],
```

So, when I add a news the date is displayed properly :

[image]

But after saving the news, the time changes to :

[image]

We have already defined on php.ini `date.timezone =  Europe/London`  and on Install Tool `[SYS][phpTimeZone] = Europe/London`

Comment: check what value is saved in DB, it may be problem with MySQL?MariaDB config

Comment: I checked the DB : `tstamp` and `crdate` are correct with this value: `1620297810` . but `starttime` has this value : `1620294195`

Comment: What timezone is your database set to? Looks to me like it may be UTC

Comment: This is the current timezone of MySQL : https://i.ibb.co/xfJCKM5/image.png

Comment: Ok so that tell it to get the timezone from the PC its running on. So what is that set to

Comment: Need to ask: did you check bug reports on TYPO3 forge? There was several similar issues posted: i.e.:https://forge.typo3.org/issues/79613